# Clean up video in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Can't find an relatively easy way to make some very basic post-production clean some unwanted things from my final render video. I can re-render the video from the compositor with mask' and then re-re-render from VSE with sound' but that's not the way I'm looking for (finally I can take the rendered png's and edit them one by one in gimp...)
I'm trying to find a reasonable process for fixing some little errors in video. Example on the screenshot - from the left side there is some part of text that should not be there' for a couple of seconds.[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the VSE add a color strip
[[image: add color strip]

The sample the source frame to change color of effect strip
[image: change color sample]

Press F12 key to render a frame inot UV Image editor window then change to mask mode and add a mask.
[image: press F12 key to render a frame add a mask]

Select the color strip and add mask modifier
[image: select color strip add mask modifier]

change the effect strip's blend type to over drop
[image: change blend type to over drop]

Comment: thanx, very much, it's an option but is a very dirty method - the background i'ts not 100% white, so it's just makes a spot over, instead of really erase this. I know that in AE it's a metter of less than one minute to do this, I'm trying to prove for all the world that Blender can be used as a tool for motion graphic as well...

Comment: I've made changes to videos such as this and did it all in the 3D window, using planes to "screen" the video and place another over the affected area only during the frames required,  The material and colour is usually easily matched to the original video in plain colour cases like this.  Some part of the original video can also be used to mask something but matching those up is more demanding. .

Comment: You could of course use the Border render command in render properties to just rerender that little portion, then alpha it over the rest.

Comment: 3pointedit: this is a veeeeery dirty method. of course it's possible to find some crazy workarounds, but the issue is to find solutions that approaching for maximum a professional work-line.

Comment: Can you explain the work flow from After Effects? Would you use a gradient object with sampled colors from the source image?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I find is to render the frame before the problematic frame and mask with it, not with color strip, like this it's match the background.
I'm using the "movie editor" for masking, not the compositor. Actually I don't know if there is a difference between using the two.